# Brainfuck compiler with tcc backend

Tags: performance, c, brainfuck

I wrote simple compiler for Brainfuck with tcc backend (dont ask for assembler/assembly code generator!). It's output runs incredibly slow. Even Hello World program takes a LOOONG while to execute. I have added some optimizations, but it didnt help. This is code i actually made; It actually doesn't hang, but output work VERY slow (i need to wait ~4 minutes to Hello World display...):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libtcc.h"

int minus(FILE* f){
    int c;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(f)) == '-')
        amount++;
    ungetc(c, f);
    return amount;
}

int plus(FILE* f){
    int c;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(f)) == '+')
        amount++;
    ungetc(c, f);
    return amount;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int pos = 0;
    int brackets = 0;
    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Brainfuck Compiler by Joel.\n");
        printf("Cannot open input file.");
        exit(0);
    }
    int amount = 1;
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    printf("Brainfuck Compiler by Joel. All rights reserved.\n");
    if(f!=NULL){
        char* outbuffer = (char*)malloc(1024*1024);
        strcpy(outbuffer, "int getch(void);\nvoid putch(int);\nint mem[65537];\nint main(){\n");
        while(!feof(f)){
            char c = fgetc(f);
            if(c == '<'){
                if(pos==0)pos=65536;
                else pos--;
            }
            if(c == '>'){
                if(pos==65536)pos=0;
                else pos++;
            }
            if(c == '['){
                brackets++;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%swhile(mem[%d]){",outbuffer,pos);
            }
            if(c == ']'){
                brackets--;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%s}", outbuffer);
            }
            if(c == '+'){
                amount = plus(f)+1;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%smem[%d]+=%d;",outbuffer, pos, amount);
            }
            if(c == '-'){
                amount = minus(f)+1;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%smem[%d]-=%d;",outbuffer, pos, amount);
            }
            if(c == '.'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%sputch(mem[%d]);",outbuffer, pos);
            }
            if(c == '.'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%smem[%d]=getch();",outbuffer, pos);
            }
        }
        if(brackets == 0){
            sprintf(outbuffer, "%sreturn 0;\n}\n",outbuffer);
            printf("Translation Succesful. ");
            compile(argv[2], outbuffer);
            free(outbuffer);
        }
        else{
            printf("Comilation fault. Unbalanced brackets.");
            free(outbuffer);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Cannot open one of specified files.");
    }
}
```

I don't think it's optimal code, and i need to "optimize" output somewhat. I have generated assembly listing here (shown with output c code): [link](https://godbolt.org/g/P7rPI3). I cant find solution, why its so SLOW. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, your code does not compile, because (at least my just installed) `libtcc` does not contain a `compile` function.

As far as I can see it, your code is that slow because you emit a `getch()` and a `putch()` when you run across a `.` (as a side note: according to MSDN, the correct signature for the latter is `int putch(int)` and both `getch()` and `putch()` are deprecated. For portability, you should use `int getchar(void)` and `int putchar(int)` anyway).

You must always check the return value of `malloc` calls, because an allocation request can fail.

You should use a `switch` instead of multiple `if` statements for handling the characters, like in the following:

```
switch (c) {
case '<':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case '>':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case '[':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case ']':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case '+':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case '-':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case '.':
    /* Do work */
    break;
case ',':
    /* Do work */
    break;
default:
    /* Comment */
    break;
}
```

The advantages are that the intention is more obvious, the compiler may be able to generate better code and it prints an error if you try to handle a character twice.

The `main` function should always return a value and that value should allow the user to distinguish between a successful compiler run and an error. So you should add a `return 0;` to the end of the function and add a `return 1;` (or whatever nonzero value you like) at the end of every error path.

You should always close files you have opened.

Error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

For protection against buffer overflows, you can use `snprintf` (which is available since C99) instead of `sprintf`. It returns either a negative value (if an error occurred) or the number of written bytes (excluding the `\0` terminator), but it does not write more than `size` bytes (including the `\0` terminator) to the output. Thus you can use

```
int ret = snprintf(outbuffer, 1024*1024, format, ...);
if (ret < 0 || ret >= 1024*1024) {
    /* Error or overflow */
    free(outbuffer);
    return 1;
}
```

Another thing you may want to consider is to reduce the memory size by one byte (thus every allowed `pos` value uses only 16 bits) and then replace

```
if (pos == 0) pos = 65536;
else pos--;
```

by

```
pos = (pos - 1) & 0xFFFF;
```

and

```
if (pos == 65536) pos = 0;
else pos++;
```

by

```
pos = (pos + 1) & 0xFFFF;
```

and thus make those two operations branchless. The effect of those two statements is that the operation is carried out on the `pos` variable, but only the lower 16 bits of the result are used (that is, `65535+1` becomes zero and `0-1` becomes `65535` (*)).

Putting all this together, you would have (including a `compile` function that can indicate an error and ):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libtcc.h>

static int compile(char const *out, char const *buf) {
    TCCState *tcc = tcc_new();
    if (tcc_set_output_type(tcc, TCC_OUTPUT_EXE) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return 1;
    }
    if (tcc_compile_string(tcc, buf) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed compiling generated code.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return 1;
    }
    if (tcc_add_library(tcc, "c") < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed linking in C library.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return 1;
    }
    if (tcc_output_file(tcc, out) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed writing program to file.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return 1;
    }
    tcc_delete(tcc);
    return 0;
}

int minus(FILE* f){
    int c;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(f)) == '-')
        amount++;
    ungetc(c, f);
    return amount;
}

int plus(FILE* f){
    int c;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(f)) == '+')
        amount++;
    ungetc(c, f);
    return amount;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    static int const buflen = 1024*1024;
    int pos = 0;
    int brackets = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "Brainfuck Compiler by Joel. All rights reserved.\n");
    if(argc!=3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <input> <output>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int amount = 0;
    int ret;
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f!=NULL){
        char* outbuffer = (char*)malloc(buflen);
        if (outbuffer == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }
        ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "int getchar(void);\nint putchar(int);\nint mem[65536] = {0};\nint main(){\n");
        if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
            free(outbuffer);
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }
        while(!feof(f)){
            switch (fgetc(f)) {
            case '<':
                pos = (pos - 1) & 0xFFFF;
                break;
            case '>':
                pos = (pos + 1) & 0xFFFF;
                break;
            case '[':
                ++brackets;
                ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%swhile(mem[%d]){", outbuffer, pos);
                if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                    free(outbuffer);
                    fclose(f);
                    return 1;
                }           
                break;
            case ']':
                --brackets;
                ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%s}", outbuffer);
                if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                    free(outbuffer);
                    fclose(f);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            case '+':
                amount = plus(f)+1;
                ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%smem[%d]+=%d;", outbuffer, pos, amount);
                if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                    free(outbuffer);
                    fclose(f);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            case '-':
                amount = minus(f)+1;
                ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%smem[%d]-=%d;", outbuffer, pos, amount);
                if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                    free(outbuffer);
                    fclose(f);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            case '.':
                ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%sputchar(mem[%d]);", outbuffer, pos);
                if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                    free(outbuffer);
                    fclose(f);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            case ',':
                ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%smem[%d]=getchar();", outbuffer, pos);
                if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                    free(outbuffer);
                    fclose(f);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
        if(brackets == 0){
            ret = snprintf(outbuffer, buflen, "%sreturn 0;\n}\n",outbuffer);
            if (ret < 0 || ret >= buflen) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Internal compiler error.\n");
                free(outbuffer);
                fclose(f);
                return 1;
            }
            if (compile(argv[2], outbuffer)) {
                free(outbuffer);
                return 1;
            }
            free(outbuffer);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Compilation fault. Unbalanced brackets.\n");
            free(outbuffer);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open one of specified files.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(*) This is only true for systems representing signed integers using two's complement, where (using signed 16 bit integers) `-1` equals `0xFFFF`. When using one's complement representation, `-1` equals `0xFFFE` (with `0xFFFF` being `-0`), but practically every machine commonly available today uses two's complement for representing signed integers.

Comment: There's a lot of duplicated code in your final code, with the `ret` check. Why do it this way and not by a function call or at least a check outside of the switch-statement?